# python argparse CIDR or network with subnet mask

Tags: python, argparse

My script takes as argument a CIDR notation of a network

```
 parser.add_argument('cidr', metavar='CIDR', type=check_cidr, nargs=1,                                                                    #
                    help='CIDR notation i.e 192.168.1.10/24')                                                                            # Argument Parser
```

In check_cidr, I verify the CIDR notation.

Would it be possible within the same parser to add another command format where it could alternatively also accept netmask notation  (i.e 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0)

Comment: Sure, just (rename and) update `check_cidr` to do that.

Comment: why so many spaces before the comment?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason you don't think it would be possible (like you tried something and it didn't work), or are you asking how but don't want to make is sound like you're asking for free code?

Comment: @tripleee But in the CIDR case there is only one argument while in the other case there are two arguments. I could of course set the number of arguments to "at least one" and validate everything within check_cidr but I was looking basically if it can be done with argparser to have two different formats.

Comment: Or require the netmask expression as a single string, perhaps like `192.168.1.10/255.255.255.0`